# Compare two or more columns in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

Database structure :

- Table name : `question`
- Columns : `qid, que, a, b, c, d, ans`

Dummy data 1:

```
Qid-1
Que-what is capital of india ?
A- mumbai
B- delhi
C-kolkata
D-chennai
Ans-B
```

Dummy data 2:

```
Qid-2
Que-formula of water ?
A- h2O
B- h30
C-h40
D-h50
Ans-A
```

Desired output :

```
Que                                ans
what is capital of india ?         Delhi
Formula of water ?                 H20
```

How to compare last column (`ans`) with other columns (`a, b, c, d`)?

I need a SQL query for that..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use case statement, like: case ans when 'A' then a when 'B' then b ...

Comment: do you want to get the que and ans only ah?

Comment: Yes i just need output que and correct ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
select que,
  switch(
    ans = 'A', A
  , ans = 'B', B
  , ans = 'C', C
  , ans = 'D', D
  )
from table1
```

OR

```
   select que, IIf(ans='A', A, IIf(ans='B',B,IIf(ans='C',C,D))) from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

As i inderstood you need decode `ans` into proper column.
Assuming that answer 'A' means: return value of column a,  answer 'B' - return value of column b etc, in Oracle I'd do it like this (not tested on real table):

```
SELECT que, decode(ans, 'A', a, 'B', b, 'C', c, 'D', d, 'No answer') FROM question
```

Pawel